# What is the keyboard shortcut for jumping into search results in Visual Studio Code (mac os)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I use CMD + SHIFT + F to go search something on VSCode. Now, after typing my search phrase, how can I jump into the search results using keyboard shortcut? The only way I know is to use TAB, but I have to press it many times before the focus reaches the actual search list. If there's a quicker way to go to the search results via keyboard, that would be awesome.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3kW1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer while looking at the Keyboard Shortcuts in settings. The shortcut is F4 (to go forward) and Shift + F4 (to go backward) to navigate between the results.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqmyp.png)

Answer (score 2):

Making any key binding you like to jump to the search results (=`"search.action.focusSearchList"`), you can use the following in your `keybindings.json` file:

(in my case I used the key binding `alt + j`)

```
    {
        "key": "alt+j",
        "command": "search.action.focusSearchList",
        "when": "searchViewletFocus"
    }
```

The key binding works when the search thingy is already in focus.

My workflow would now be:

1. `ctrl + shift + f` to search for smth.
2. `ctrl + j`
3. use arrows (default) or j (vim plugin) to go through search results
4. hit enter on a search results to start editing.

Comment: This is the secret sauce I was looking for. Thank you sir! 

Answer (score 0):

For those who want to navigate between results without touching the mouse.

If you press `F4`, your caret will be placed inside any found file, preventing you from usign the arrows to navigate between the found results.
The only way I've found to focus the results is by invoking `Search: Collapse All` which I've bound to `alt + -`.

So: ctrl+shift+f -> 'foo' -> F4 -> alt+- -> arrowUp/Down...

I would like VSCode to improve keyboard usability by default... till then there's some mazes to solve unfortunately.